# Delete sub-array from array if condition (on both key AND value) is met

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have a big array of identical sub-arrays, a minimal example may look like:

```
array(4) {
  [0]=>
  array(2) {
    ["id_product"]=>
    string(4) "1372"
    ["quantity"]=>
    int(0)
   }
  [1]=>
  array(2) {
    ["id_product"]=>
    string(4) "1373"
    ["quantity"]=>
    int(1)
   }
  [2]=>
  array(2) {
    ["id_product"]=>
    string(4) "1374"
    ["quantity"]=>
    int(2)
   }
  [3]=>
  array(2) {
    ["id_product"]=>
    string(4) "1375"
    ["quantity"]=>
    int(0)
   }
}
```

My goal is to create a new array excluding the sub-arrays with `quantity` equal to `int(0)`, what might give something like:

```
array(4) {
  [1]=>
  array(2) {
    ["id_product"]=>
    string(4) "1373"
    ["quantity"]=>
    int(1)
   }
  [2]=>
  array(2) {
    ["id_product"]=>
    string(4) "1374"
    ["quantity"]=>
    int(2)
   }
}
```

I tried using `array_search()` and `unset()` but to no avail. Any suggestions on how to use these functions so that I can exclude any subarray with condition like : `sub-key`= x and `value` = y.

Thank you very much for helping me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A prefect situation to use [array_filter()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php)

```
$newArray = array_filter(
    $originalArray,
    function($value) {
        return $value['quantity'] > 0;
    }
);
```

Comment: The question required filtering out elements in an array, based on a condition, and creating a newly filtered array. A perfect case for using array_filter()

Comment: This worked perfectly for me, It addressed the problem like a charm. I think some upvotes should be put here instead of downvoting because the use of `unset` and `array_search` was a waste of time(for me).

Comment: Perhaps I was downvoted for my spelling of `perfect`

Answer (score 1):

Try your custom code

```
function array_filter(){
    $newArray = array();
    foreach($array as $key => $value){
        if($value["quantity"] > 0)
            $newArray[] = $value
    }
    return $newArray;
}
```

**Enjoy :)**